# Dynamically define function in Bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have what I thought was a simple problem - but I simply can't solve it.
I have a API that I'm using that returns a `function` for me to call when all my code is complete. I had thought that I could just put the function in a `finally` call - but it seems I can't redefine functions during a promise chain.

A simple example:

```
let a= function() {console.log("at the start");};
BbPromise.resolve("Executing")
    .tap(console.log)
    .then(function() {a = function() {console.log("at the end");}})
    .finally(a);
```

How would I go about getting `"At the end"` to print out, at the end? This example will always print `"At the start"`. If I use strings instead of functions, it works as expected.

Comment: What exactly is that API doing? Can you link its docs, or post your actual code?

Comment: The API is actually returning a function that allows me to delete a message retrieved from a queue. The library is sqs-consumer - which I have promisifed, but I still need to deal with an onDone callback after checking the message

Comment: If you mean the `create` function, I don't think you can promisify that. `handleMessage` is called multiple times, not only once like a promise that resolves. You should just be doing `function handleMessage(msg, done) { doWhateverYouNeedToDoThatReturnsAPromise(msg).asCallback(done); }`. The only thing that would make sense is to decorate `create` so that `handleMessage` can be a promise-returning function instead of a callback-receiving one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `a` to the `finally` call before you overwrite it from the asynchronous callback - [a classic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).

You just have to dereference `a` in the `finally` callback:

```
.finally(function() { a(); })
```

Of course, notice that redefining a function is weird and there is probably a better a approach to solve your actual problem. If you expect to get a promise for a function, you shouldn't make a global variable for the function but rather do `.then(fn => fn())`.

Comment: Perfect! Unfortunately the library I'm using doesn't return a promise, and I don't get visibility of function it returns until after events have fired - via a callback. Any better solution would be gladly welcomed though!

Comment: @Silver: Please show us the exact code you're using for sqs-consumer, and we may be able to help you improve it. You should ask a new question for that, possible at [codereview.SE].